# If we decide to use attribute groups together with populations would it lead to contacts duplication?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

For one specific use case we need to use both attribute groups based on DEs and populations. We want to double-check if it could potentially lead to contacts duplication in Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Deduplication is based on the Contact Key, meaning one and the same key is one contact - no matter where it's from and in how many relevant locations the key is.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5

> > "Contact Deduplication
> >
> > Contacts count only one time."

You will only get "deduplication" issues (too many keys per person) if several types of keys exist for the same person, e.g. lead / contact, or disparate source systems with disparate IDs.

Comment: thank you for your comment. My question was more about Attributes groups and Populations working together. General logic behind contacts creation process in MC is clear to me. Have you ever used Populations in MC together with attribute groups containing the same contacts?

Comment: Hi, sorry, then I don't really understand the question. What do you mean by contact duplication?